# Changes made to (static) CSS file not reflecting in Django development server

Tags: css, django

I am making a Web app using Django and was having some trouble getting the changes made in the CSS file (which is stored in the static directory of my app) to reflect onto the development server.

To be clear the server is able to access static files, however, it is currently stuck on an old iteration of my CSS file. A similar problem had occurred a few weeks ago, when any change I made to the CSS file wasn't showing up. That problem fixed itself after a few days.

However, not getting immediate visual feedback is extremely frustrating. I have tried all of the following to rectify the problem:

- My DEBUG is set to 'True'
- I have provided a STATIC_URL
- I tried 'collecting' the static files. The command worked but the dev server is still not reflecting changes made to the CSS file
- I provided a STATIC_ROOT, STATICFILES_DIR and STATICFILES_FINDER. Currently these are commented out as I realized some of these are for production only or are unnecessary for development.

My static resources are kept in the 'static' directory of one of my apps -- 'post_it_gen' which is part of the project. According to the documentation this should be automatically searched by Django.

Any new suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more code (e.g. the relevant settings). As per http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979340/928098 you do not need to `collectstatic` with the dev server. Are you sure you're modifying the right CSS file? (Please show full filepaths)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you develop locally using Django's server there's no need to use the `collectstatic` command, it is only meant to collect all static dependencies to a single access point where you can point your 'real' server to, e.g. apache, lighttpd, nginx etc.

As for your problem, you insinuate it 'magically' fixes it self after a few days. Have you tried resetting your browser's cache?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, resetting the cache solved it :)

Comment: I had often the same problem with caches. I found resetting the cache every now and then quite annoying, so I figured out a more practical way: loading the page in an incognito window.

Comment: another option would be to mark "no cache" in google development tools advanced settings, however this only works when the window is active. Another cool chrome feature is to hold down the refresh button, you get 3 options on how to reload the page (this also only works when the dev tools window is opened).

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide lol.. I never know this option.. this worked.. for me

Answer (score 8):

In my case, my browser was caching the Js and CSS files and thus I was unable to see the changes.  
You can try hard refreshing the page 
 
For chrome/chromium browsers: 
Ctrl + F5 or Ctrl + Shift + R 
both works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Do a Hard Refresh in Browser 
Firefox: 
    Window, Linux: 1.]  `ctrl` + `F5` 2.] `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R` 
    Mac 1.] `Command` + `Shift` + `R`
Chrome:
    Window, Linux: 1.]  `ctrl` + `F5` 2.] `Ctrl` + `usual refresh`
    Mac 1.] `Command` + `Shift` + `R` 2.] `Ctrl` + `usual refresh`
Safari:
    Mac 1.] `Shift` + `Command` + `R`

Answer (score 2):

clearing cache worked for me.
after deleting it 2 times, changes are displayed by just refresh button

Answer (score 2):

just try hard refreshing the page
For chrome/chromium browsers:

Ctrl + Shift + R

it's done!

Answer (score 0):

Use incognito mode to test the changes, as the normal window will keep saving your changes in cache which is not the case with incognito window.

Answer (score 0):

If its not updating the css you changed. first make sure you are making changes in static file directory.
After making that changes run command python manage.py collectstatic
and then runserver.

Make sure to refresh browser by ctrl and f5.
Hopefully it will works. peace

Answer (score 0):

(1)Simply I first remove CSS file from static folder and after that I refresh Server.

(2)After that my template did not reflect any CSS to my html page

(3) After that I simply restore my same name edited css file in static folder and it work properly .

(4) After that your CSS is not run properly than you should add this directory in settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
              ]
```

*If not your CSS not apply just check your all link code  should be

Answer (score 0):

You may also have making changes to the wrong javascript file - specifically you need to make changes to the version under /media/... and NOT to the version under /static/...