# Bootstrap 4 form change checkbox valid style

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi currently i'm using bootstrap 4 for my form validation, in the checkbox field i have after a user click submit if the checkbox is tick then it's valid and the text with the box border will change to green color #28a745.

But currently i don't want to change the color of the border of the box and text to green if it's valid:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```css
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before,
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: #495C83 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="container needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" class="custom-control-input" tabindex="3" id="remember-me" checked="">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="remember-me">Nhớ đăng nhập</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" tabindex="4">
                      Đăng Nhập
                    </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

**Ignore the javascript part i just use it so it show the after user checked and press submit effect**

Currently after on validate success the text and border of the checkbox change to green color but i don't want the color to change

[image: after validate]

So i tried to overriding the boostrap custom class that cause the green border and green text on validate success which is this :

```
.custom-control-input.is-valid~.custom-control-label, .was-validated .custom-control-input:valid~.custom-control-label {
    color: #28a745;
}
.custom-control-input.is-valid:checked~.custom-control-label::before, .was-validated .custom-control-input:valid:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    border-color: #34ce57;
    background-color: #34ce57;
}
.custom-control-input.is-valid~.custom-control-label::before, .was-validated .custom-control-input:valid~.custom-control-label::before {
    border-color: #28a745;
}
```

so i changed it to:

```
.custom-control-input.is-valid~.custom-control-label, .was-validated .custom-control-input:valid~.custom-control-label {
    color: #495C83 !important;
}
.custom-control-input.is-valid:checked~.custom-control-label::before, .was-validated .custom-control-input:valid:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    border-color: #495C83 !important;
    background-color: #495C83 !important;
}
.custom-control-input.is-valid~.custom-control-label::before, .was-validated .custom-control-input:valid~.custom-control-label::before {
    border-color: #495C83 !important;
}
```

But the color still show up as green after validation.
I don't know why this doesn't work in my css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why since i'm working on django project , i need to clear browser cache to see the reflect of css change explained in this question [css files on django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978148/changes-made-to-static-css-file-not-reflecting-in-django-development-server)

After clearing the cache i refresh the page and i see the changes now so the css i used was correct

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you added "was validated" to the entire form. Try removing `form.classList.add('was-validated')` and you should also clear cache to ensure your browser isn't caching the previous styles.